# How to convert string to boolean in lua

Tags: lua

I have data received from another script where the variable has the value "false" or "true". I want to convert this value to true or false in lua datatype. Currently, I can do this long way:

```
if value == "false" then
  value=false
elseif value == "true" then
  value=true
end
```

Is there a simplest way to convert this like converting string to integer tonumber("1")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
stringtoboolean={ ["true"]=true, ["false"]=false }
print(stringtoboolean[s])
```

Comment: Is this enum type? Nice solution but I hate the `[ ]`

Comment: No, it's a Lua table: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9 -- the given code just defines a table mapping the string form to the boolean form and then looks up the value in it.

Comment: You won't get far without `[ ]`. It is used to index the most important data type in Lua so better stop hating it ;-)

Comment: You can set a call metamethod and use `stringtoboolean(s)` if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

No, because `"false"` will also evaluate to `true`, so if you want `"false"` to evaluate to `false`, you will have to convert it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Since I frequently do the conversion for each data received, manually converting the string to boolean like I posted above will make the code redundant. So I create a function to overcome this:

```
function toboolean(str)
    local bool = false
    if str == "true" then
        bool = true
    end
    return bool
end
```

So I can do this

```
toboolean("true")
```

and anything other than the "true" string will become false

Comment: Since this returns `true` for `"true"` and `false` for everything else, you could simplify it to: `function toboolean(str) return str == "true" end`

Answer (score 2):

Then there's always

```
 str=="true" and true or false
```

the lua simulation of a ternary operator, or for case independence

```
 (str and string.lower(str))=="true" and true or false
```

the short-circuit evaluation will prevent an exception if str==nil

Answer (score 1):

Case independent way:

```
function str_to_bool(str)
    if str == nil then
        return false
    end
    return string.lower(str) == 'true'
end
```